# Flow of a use-case

Tags: uml, use-case

If use-case A extends use-case B, does that mean A is complete and flow shifted to B or flow will return to A?

Does UML put any restrictions on that? Or does it depend on the modeler?

Answer (score 4):

"extends" in use-case terminology *is not a sequential control-flow relationship*; "A extends B" means that under certain circumstances use-case A occurs *in addition to* use-case B. Use-case B can stand alone, use-case A cannot (as it depends on B). Use-case A occurs at an 'extension point' in use-case B.

please review the [definitions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cextend.html) it sounds like there is some confusion

Comment: +1: usually we put "Extension Point" in A to show places where it will be extended.  And in B we specifically say where and how it extends A.  It's just doco -- it doesn't have to compile -- it only has to be clear.